# Creating Java object from clojure

Tags: java, clojure

I'm trying to start with Apache Jena in Clojure, so I have added library to resources folder.

Now I want to create Jena Model.

In Java, it would be

```
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
```

I guess in Clojure it would be something like this

```
(def model (ModelFactory/createDefaultModel))
```

But I'm not sure about this. I guess this could work for String but I don't know if it would work for custom object.

Comment: This isn't a question.

Comment: `not sure`? => REPL. But what you have should "do it". Don't believe me? => REPL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indeed.
with the following in your project.clj:

```
  [org.apache.jena/jena-arq "2.10.0"]
```

then you can use:

```
  (def model (com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory/createDefaultModel))
```

Comment: additionally, if you `(import '(com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model ModelFactory))` first, you can use the def form in the original code unchanged

Answer (score 0):

Well the official way to deal with Java static methods is:

```
(ClassName/methodName arguments)
```

Have you tried your line in the REPL any way?